# Pagination outside of loop

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I am trying to figure out how to add pagination to a page without messing up my code. My code is as following

```
<?php if (is_page ( array ( 'news' , 'hotspots' ) ) ) {  

// beveiligingscheck voor het plaatsen van items

$count_posts = 0 ; 

if (is_page ( 'hotspots' ) ) {

    $type = 'trends';

    $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'trends' )->publish ;

} elseif (is_page ( 'news' ) ) {

    $type = array('post', 'mood', 'trends' , 'interior') ;

    $count_posts_1 = wp_count_posts( 'post' )->publish ;

    $count_posts_2 = wp_count_posts( 'mood' )->publish ;

    $count_posts_3 = wp_count_posts( 'trends' )->publish ;

    $count_posts_4 = wp_count_posts( 'interior' )->publish ;

    $count_posts = (int) $count_posts_1 +  (int) $count_posts_2 +  (int) $count_posts_3 +  (int) $count_posts_4;

}



if ( $count_posts > 0 ) {

// functie om de query te bepalen

    function display_imagepost($type, $number) {

        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        $args = array(
            'offset' => $number,
            'post_status' =>'publish',
            'post_type' => $type,
            'posts_per_page' => 14,
            'paged' => $paged
        );

        $item = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $item->have_posts() ) {

            // variabelen

            $postid = $item->post->ID;
            $posttitle = $item->post->post_title;
            $imagelink = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($postid) );
            $url =  get_permalink( $item->post->ID );

            echo "<a href='".$url."' class='gallerylink'>";                                             
            echo "<img src='".$imagelink."' class='fade' align='middle'>"; 
            echo "</a>";            

         } 

    }   

?>

<section class="custom-gallery">

    <div class="row m-all t-all d-all cf">

        <?php #first inner section ?>

        <div class="sub-row m-all t-1of3 d-1of3 double-height">

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 0);?>

                </div>  

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php #second inner section ?>

        <div class="sub-row m-all t-2of3 d-2of3">

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all">

                <div class="element m-all t-1of2 d-1of2">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 1);?>

                </div>

                <div class="element m-all t-1of2 d-1of2">


                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 2);?>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all double-width">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 3);?>

                </div>

            </div>          


        </div>

    </div>

<?php 

}

  if ( $count_posts > 0 &&  $count_posts > 4 ) 

 {

 ?> 

    <div class="row m-all t-all d-all cf">

        <?php #first inner section ?>

        <div class="sub-row m-all t-1of3 d-1of3">

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 4);?>

                </div>  

            </div>

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 5);?>

                </div>  

            </div>                                              

        </div>

        <?php #second inner section ?>

        <div class="sub-row m-all t-2of3 d-2of3">

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all double-width double-height">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 6);?>

                </div>

            </div>          

        </div>

    </div>

<?php 

}

if ( $count_posts > 0 &&  $count_posts > 7 ) 

{

?>  

    <div class="row m-all t-all d-all cf">

        <?php #first inner section ?>

        <div class="sub-row m-all t-2of3 d-2of3">

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all">

                <div class="element m-all t-1of2 d-1of2">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 7);?>

                </div>

                <div class="element m-all t-1of2 d-1of2">


                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 8);?>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all double-width">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 9);?>

                </div>

            </div>                  

        </div>

        <?php #second inner section ?>

        <div class="sub-row m-all t-1of3 d-1of3 double-height">

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 10);?>

                </div>  

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

<?php 

}

if ( $count_posts > 0 &&  $count_posts > 11 ) 

{

?>  

    <div class="row m-all t-all d-all cf">

        <?php #thirdinner section ?>

        <div class="sub-row m-all t-2of3 d-2of3">

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all double-width double-height">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 11);?>

                </div>

            </div>          

        </div>


        <?php #second inner section ?>

        <div class="sub-row m-all t-1of3 d-1of3">

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 12);?>

                </div>  

            </div>

            <div class="element-row m-all t-all d-all">

                <div class="element m-all t-all d-all">

                    <?php display_imagepost($type, 13);?>

                </div>  

            </div>                                              

        </div>

    </div>                                  


<?php

 next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $item->max_num_pages );
 previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
 ?>

 <?php 

 wp_reset_postdata(); 
 ?>

<?php           

} elseif ($count_posts === 0 || $count_posts < 1) {

    echo "no data retrieved";

}

echo "</section>";

}   

?>
```

Now I am aware there is no loop here, just a query that i read out and i use those variables of the 14 items that are being returned (offically 20, but i dont use those at the moment just yet)

But there is no pagination displayed. i guess it has to do with the fact i dont run a loop, but is there a way i can add an pagination in here as well, or do i need to rewrite my code? The thing is if i run this in a loop is that my mark up with mess up, because no code block aint the same since it has to be tucked in a lay-out.